# How to use A3 certificates with Indy 10 on Delphi XE5?

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy, pfx

I need to connect to a WebService and validate my connection using a digital certificate. My clients have two types of certificates: A1 (pfx file) and A3 (token or smartcard).

I was able to use A1 certificates (pfx files), but now I want to know how to ask for an A3 certificate on my application for later use with Indy.

The point is: how to list the Windows' installed/available certificates? With this list, how to use the selected certificate with Indy?

The A3 certificates are selectable through the Windows' certificates stores. Below is a screenshot

[image: Selecting a certificate]

Using CAPICOM e WININET I can show this dialog box and "apply" the selected certificate to the connection using InternetSetOptions, and I can also do it using pfx files.

I want to use Indy to have more control about the used protocol (TLS 1.2), because using WININET (Delphi Default for WebServices) the protocol depends on the Internet Options. See below:

[image: Internet Options]

Comment: I have no idea how to use smartcard certificates with OpenSSL (but it is possible), but Indy certainly does not support using them when configuring the OpenSSL context. It only supports certificate files.

Comment: Sorry @RemyLebeau, my proficiency in english is poor. I meaned "use smartcard / token to validate a connection to a WebService which is made through SSL". In fact I found that Indy works only with certificate files and I am doing a workaround to save the certificate on A3 to a pfx file, and only so use it with indy and SSL. I do not know if this will work, but I will try. Would be great if Indy could load pfx files directy. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: OpenSSL can convert PFX files, but I don't think it can actually use PFX files as-is, it wants PEM files instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I edited my question to clarify some things

Comment: OpenSSL does not support the Windows certificate store and WinInet does not use OpenSSL. Anything that is in the Windows certificate store would have to be exported (and possibly converted) to use it with OpenSSL.